# HawkBit - Custom theme in docker image

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I would like to create a new color scheme on the server's management UI page. According to the instructions from the [help page](https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/guides/customtheme/):

- I created my own theme containing color changes
- I changed the configuration to make my theme work (hawkbit-ui/src/main/java/org/eclipse/hawkbit/ui/themes/HawkbitTheme.java)
- Build repo and run the server

I have noticed the color changes that I made. The target configuration is to run in docker containers. In this case, I rebuilt the server locally and ran it without using a container.

I wonder if in that case I will have to rebuild the entire repository, create a docker image, and mount such a custom container on my server?

**Is it possible to add a theme to the docker image downloaded by default by dockercompose, and enable this theme by adding some entry to the application.properties file?** If possible, then:

- What would that entry be?
- Where to copy theme files to container filesystem from hawkBit?

Tried: Look for some hints in documentation. Expectations: Find out if it is possible to add a theme to the finished docker image. If it is possible, how to do it?